# Pygame window initiates frozen

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote a small code to try working with pygame for the first time, but I'm having trouble getting the game window to respond to any input at all including the exit button. No matter if I run the code through Sublime, VScode, or Python the window loads fine but the sprite takes no input (so fare I have only coded left) nor will the window close. If I want to close the window I have to close whatever editor/terminal I'm running the program through

```
import pygame
import os 


pygame.display.set_caption("CyberPunk 3077")
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
PLAYER, SIZE = 34, 34
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
'''We have now created the window and it's size
Now lets create the background display'''

FPS = 60
VELOCITY = 3 
WHITE = ((255, 255, 255))
MID_BORDER = pygame.Rect((WIDTH/2)-2.5, 0,5, HEIGHT) #this will place a solid line in the middle of the screen


Player_1 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('skins', 'player.png')), (PLAYER,SIZE))
P1 = pygame.transform.rotate(Player_1, 270)
Player_2 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('skins', 'enemy.png')), (PLAYER,SIZE))
P2 = pygame.transform.rotate(Player_2, 270)
SKY = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('skins', 'bg.png')), (WIDTH,HEIGHT))
#this will search our folder 'skins' for the file 'bg' to make our background

def draw(yellow, blue):
    WIN.blit(SKY, (0,0)) 
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, WHITE, MID_BORDER)
    WIN.blit(P1, (yellow.y, yellow.y))
    WIN.blit(P2, (blue.x, blue.y))
    #pygame starts tracking at the top left with 0,0
    pygame.display.update()

def P1_moves(keys_pressed, yellow):
    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and yellow.x - VELOCITY > 0: #LEFT
        yellow.x -= VELOCITY
'''this is the only instance of movement I have coded so far. Didn't want to continue if I can't even get 'left' to work '''
    


def main():
    yellow = pygame.Rect(200, 250, 32, 32)
    blue = pygame.Rect(650, 250, 32, 32)

    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run == False
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        P1_moves(keys_pressed, yellow)
        draw(yellow, blue)
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `run = False` instead of `run == False`

Comment: `WIN.blit(P1, (yellow.x, yellow.y))` instead of `WIN.blit(P1, (yellow.y, yellow.y))`

Comment: Thank you @Rabbid76! I think I was to close to the problem to see those very obvious mistakes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rabbid76 answered this problem in a comment.
`run = False` instead of `run == False`

> WIN.blit(P1, (yellow.x, yellow.y)) instead of WIN.blit(P1, (yellow.y, yellow.y))

Rabbid76 Sep 15 at 18:18

Answer (score 0):

The `keys_pressed[pygame.K_a]` should be `keys_pressed[pygame.K_A]` (capital 'A').

Comment: K_a worked fine after I changed the suggestions Rabbid had said. I now have full movements for both sprites and firing actions this was my first attempt at pygame so I was lost at first. Thank you though. I'm not sure how to mark this as completed.